# Asus EeePC 1001P: Using Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, netbook

My girlfriend just bought an Asus EeePC 1001P and it comes loaded with Windows 7 Starter, which is pretty frustratingly limited. I have several Action Pack licenses for Windows 7 Pro, and was wondering if installing that would still run smoothly and not destroy performance or battery life.

Anyone know if Windows 7 Pro will run acceptably on a netbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no performance differences between the two SKUs. Simply a licensing/feature difference.

Answer (score 1):

It should be no problem, but Aero won't run if there is not enough graphics memory. Upgrade to 2gb ram on the main memory.

You might take note of all the power options settings before installing W7, then check to see if they are the same after installation.

I ran W7 Pro for a year on an atom 230 processor (Desktop), it was acceptable, it should run well on the N450